# Can verb 'grant' be used with preposition 'with?'

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

Could someone explain to me if the word 'grant' can be used with 'with' and what it means? 
(I checked with many dictionaries, but couldn't find an example used in that way.)

example sentence in an editorial today:

> Russia’s yatra is an opportunity for Kim to grant his country with a multi-dimensional defence and diplomatic perspective and open up to all those who wish to see a more interdependent and proactive communist state across the Armistice line.

Comment: No; _grant_ can take both a direct and an indirect object: _Russia’s yatra is an opportunity for Kim to grant his country a multi-dimensional defence ..._, but is not used in a parallel structure to '... bless Joan with ...'.

Comment: I saw Cary Grant with Deborah Kerr in an Affair to Remember.

Answer (score 1):

While perfectly understandable the combination "grant with" sounds awkward. More normal sounding is "provide his country with..."

Comment: Very helpful comment.

Comment: [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+was+granted+a%2Che+was+granted+with+a&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20was%20granted%20a%3B%2Cc0) seem to show that 'grant with a' is _extremely_ rare.